# Updating json model swiftUI

Tags: json, swift

I currently have a json file that stores data persistently in my app. The json data looks like this:

```swift
[
  {
    "id": "C8B046E9-70F5-40D4-B19A-40B3E0E0877B",
    "name": "Dune",
    "author": "Frank Herbert",
    "genre": "Science fiction",
    "page": "77",
    "total": "420"
  },
  {
    "id": "2E27CA7C-ED1A-48C2-9B01-A122038EB67A",
    "name": "Ready Player One",
    "author": "Ernest Cline",
    "genre": "Science fiction",
    "page": "234",
    "total": "420"
  }
]
```

It decodes from and encodes into an array of objects with the following global functions:

```swift
func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {

    let readURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "json")!
    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    
    let jsonURL = documentDirectory
        .appendingPathComponent(filename)
        .appendingPathExtension("json")

// the code takes my example books from my bundle if they are a new user

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: jsonURL.path) {
        try? FileManager.default.copyItem(at: readURL, to: jsonURL)
    }
    return try! JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: Data(contentsOf: jsonURL))
}

func writeJSON(_ bookData: [Book]) {
    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let jsonURL = documentDirectory
        .appendingPathComponent("list")
        .appendingPathExtension("json")
    try? JSONEncoder().encode(bookData).write(to: jsonURL, options: .atomic)
}
```

and here's the struct

```swift
struct Book: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var author: String
    var genre: String
    var page: String
    var total: String
}
```

I now want to add a new key to the data (for example another string). If I just update my struct and , the apps of existing users will crash considering their json files will be missing the new keys and jsondecoder won't be able to decode them. I load the data into my list with a variable in my view `@State var bookData: [Book] = load("list")`

How can I best update my json model? I tried adding a condition to the load function that takes the original data, adds the new keys and store it in a new file to load however I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Either make the new property optional or make sure it gets a default value for older items.

Comment: How can I initialize the older items with a value, considering the file is already written once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a default value for the new property and set it in a custom `init` or make the new property optional. Below is an example of both

```
struct Book: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var author: String
    var genre: String
    var page: String
    var total: String

    var newProp: String
    var newOptionalProp: String?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(UUID.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        author = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .author)
        genre = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .genre)
        page = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .page)
        total = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .total)

        if let newPropValue = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .newProp) {
            newProp = newPropValue
        } else {
            newProp = "Some default value"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example

```
let data = """
  {
    "id": "C8B046E9-70F5-40D4-B19A-40B3E0E0877B",
    "name": "Dune",
    "author": "Frank Herbert",
    "genre": "Science fiction",
    "page": "77",
    "total": "420"
  }
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Book.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

> Book(id: C8B046E9-70F5-40D4-B19A-40B3E0E0877B, name: "Dune", author: "Frank Herbert", genre: "Science fiction", page: "77", total: "420", newProp: "Some default value", newOptionalProp: nil)

Comment: This is much better than my implementation, thank you

Comment: Hey, so the init worked for the load but whenever I try to create a Book elsewhere (for example before appending one to the array, it now needs the decoder. For example, here's the test book I use for previews ```let testData = [Book(id: UUID(), name: "Dune", author: "Frank Herbert",genre: "Science fiction", page: "5", total: "10")]``` and I get this error ```Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call```

Comment: @ArnavMotwani, just create a new `init` with parameters for all properties (or create test data from json)

Comment: The test data was an example, suppose I want to add a new object to my json. I create a new Book with the user entered values and then I append it to the array before writing it to file, what do I use as for the decoder.  ```bookData.append(Book(id: UUID(), name: name, author: author,genre: genre, page: page, total: total))``` all the variables (like name and author) are State wrapped for text fields. I still get the same error

Comment: @ArnavMotwani, json was just another option, my main point was that you create a new `init`, like `init(name: String, author: String, genre: String, page: String, total: String) {...}`